# Scheme - How to use "." as a symbol

Tags: scheme

I want to do something like:

```
(car '(. a))
```

and get

```
.
```

as a result.

For example, if you type

```
'.
```

into the console you will get the output that I want. The problem is that I don't want to have an apostrophe infront of all of the . in a list.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Scheme's read syntax, a standalone dot is special. `'.` won't get you a dot symbol; it's invalid syntax. (If it works in your implementation, then that's just a special quirk of your implementation.)

Instead, you have to escape it. In most Scheme implementations, you can either use `'|.|` or `'\.`.

```
(car '(\. a))   ; returns the same thing as (string->symbol ".")
(car '(|.| a))  ; likewise
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This appears to only work in MIT/GNU Scheme.

`'` creates symbol and list literals. If you want `.` as a symbol, it's `'.`.

If `a` is a symbol literal, you can use

```
(car '(. a))
```

or

```
(car (list '. 'a))
```

If `a` is a variable, try

```
(car `(. ,a))
```

or

```
(car (list '. a))
```

Comment: Try (car '(. a)) ... it doesn't work for me :( . This is the problem that I'm trying to fix actually.

Comment: Huh. Worked for me (MIT/GNU Scheme) but that might be an implementation thing.

Comment: The other answer here suggests that your solution is invalid syntax... Who's right? :)

Comment: Going by R5RS, I think they are. Mine works under MIT/GNU Scheme but apparently not under Racket.