# about the dot "." in scheme

Tags: scheme, symbols

I saw there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986664/scheme-how-to-use-as-a-symbol) about the dot "."
I followed but it didn't work for my code.... 
it's a part of code, the implementation is not focused to this symbol.
but output should be included this dot. 
when I give input of two lists '(1 2 3) '(4 5)
my expected output => (1 . 4) (2 . 5)

I managed to get (1 4) (2 5)
just need to add "." in the middle.

```
Part of mycode 
(cons (list (car lst1) (car lst2))
....
```

for the "." symbol , if I try

```
**trial-1**
 (cons '(list (car lst1) (car lst2)) ...)
```

then the output : ((list (car lst1) (car lst2))

```
**trail-2**
(cons (list (car lst1) '. (car lst2)) ...)
```

then.. it says : illegal use of `.'

what are the rules to use the dot? any documents I can look at? 
btw, I am using Racket(R5RS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dot symbol is displayed when you build a `cons`-*pair* or a *list* which is not *proper* (meaning: it doesn't end with the empty list). For example:

```
(cons 1 2) 
=> (1 . 2) ; a cons-pair

(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 4)))
=> '(1 2 3 . 4) ; an improper list
```

For instance, to display an output such as the one shown in the question try this:

```
(define lst1 '(1 2 3))
(define lst2 '(4 5))

(list (cons (car lst1) (car lst2))
      (cons (cadr lst1) (cadr lst2)))

=> '((1 . 4) (2 . 5))
```

Comment: my code was ... cons(list... and your code... list(cons... => (I just try with my own words, to see I understand it correctly) ; so because  the dotted symbol will be "automatically" displayed when I build cons-pair. but my mistake was I build a list first and then cons-pair so it doesn't show the dotted symbol because a list is not proper to display the dotted symbol. but if the code is build cons-pair first, then build a list from the cons-pair result, so that will show the the dotted symbol.... right?

Comment: @user1915570 mmm, I'd better say that the dot symbol has a special meaning, so you can't use is as a "normal" symbol. It's shown when you display `cons` cells with a certain structure, but you can't add it explicitly to your lists

Comment: there is also you explained "meaning:it doesn't end with the empty list". what exactly this mean? because my original code actually a part of tail recursion practice again.. so when I did... (a part of code)  ...(list (cons (car lst1) (car lst2))
            (myFunc (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)).... myFunc is the tail recursion part... output is like this : (myFunc '(1 2 3) '(a b c)) => ((1 . a) ((2 . b) ((3 . c) ())))  .... I get the empty list in the end.

Comment: It means that this is an _improper_ list (it doesn't end in an empty list): `(cons 1 (cons 2 3))`, and on the other hand this is a _proper_ list (it ends with an empty list): `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`. Evaluate them and see the difference.

Comment: There is such a thing as a "normal" dot symbol, and in R7RS, you write it using `|.|`. However, that's completely different from the dot you're talking about here. :-) For the OP's benefit, I mean: `'(a . b)` is a single cons cell, with symbol `a` as its car, and symbol `b` as its cdr. `'(a |.| b)` is a proper list with 3 elements (i.e., 3 cons cells), the symbols `a`, `.`, and `b`.

Comment: I think I didn't understand completely. I will put new question with my entire code - I try to avoid that.. but I think I need to show what I did...

Answer (score 3):

Although `.` can be a part of a symbol, `.` is not in itself a valid symbol. `.` is used in list structure as a divider between the `car` and the `cdr`. eg. `(a . (b . (c . ()))) ; ==> (a b c)`.

Practical application is the historic use as a rest argument in the prototype of a procedure and you can use it as template an transformation of macros. Also, `read` can read it in and you can use it as data like `(define lst '((a) . (b)))`.

So to recap:

`(a . b)` is a pair of `a` and `b`, while `(a.b)` is the same as `(a.b . ())` thus a pair of  the symbol `a.b` and the empty list.

As for how to create a pair you use `cons`. `(cons 'a 'b) => (a . b)` while `(list a b) => (cons 'a (cons b '()))`. Now you can make a pair with two lists as arguments, `(cons '(1 4) '(2 5))` but if you print it you know that `(a . (b))` is the same as `(a b)` thus `(cons '(1 4) '(2 5))` will display as `((1 4) 2 5)` since it will prefer not to display the dot. If it would prefer to show dots it would have displayed it as `((1 . (4 . ())) .  ((2 . (5 . ()))))` instead since thats how many pairs there are in that data structure.

If you have managed to get the output `((1 4) (2 5))` and really wanted `((1 . 4) (2 . 5))` you need to replace a `list` with `cons`.

Comment: yes, I did.. but then I get empty list at the end.. I think I didn't understand completely. I will put new question with my entire code - I try to avoid that.. but I think I need to show what I did...

Comment: @user1915570 You've switched the outer `cons` with `list`. When iterating a list you need to join by pairs using cons since the tail recursion creates a list and `(cons 'first '(the rest of the result))` becomes `(first the rest of the result)` while every part with `list` becomes `(first (the (rest (of (the (result ()))))))`. Since  `(list a b)` is `(cons a (cons b '()))`. Try keep from using `list` at all for a while to get a hang of it at least for small lists. so instead of `(list (list a) b c)` do `(cons (cons a '()) (cons b (cons c '())))`

Answer (score 1):

It's called a dotted pair and is produced when you `cons` an item with a non-list, such as:

```
> (cons 1 2)
(1 . 2)
```

See: http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/html/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Scheme_Syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

From R7RS:

> The most general notation (external representation) for Scheme pairs
>   is the “dotted” notation (c1 . c2) where c1 is the value of the car
>   field and c2 is the value of the cdr field. For example (4 . 5) is a
>   pair whose car is 4 and whose cdr is 5. Note that (4 . 5) is the
>   external repre- sentation of a pair, not an expression that evaluates
>   to a pair.

`.` is not a symbol.