# Improper vs. proper list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, cons

The original code I try to implement.. the output should be (1.4) (2.5) from my code.. I think you all know what I try to do....this is also tail recursion practice

```
my code
(define (myFunc lst1 lst2)
 (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))       
    '()                                  
     (list (cons (car lst1) (car lst2))
        (myFunc (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
  ))
```

after several of you gave me [good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620331/about-the-dot-in-scheme) about cons-pair.. so now it get's the dotted symbol in the middle.. then problem is that the improper list with empty list in the end..
 when 2 input lists are like this ..... '(1 2 3 4) '(4 5 6))
my output is like this ; ((1 . 4) ((2 . 5) ((3 . 6) ()))) 
the empty list in the end of output shouldn't be there... so I couldn't understand about improper list , proper list....? is there are any document, I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the difference between `cons` and `list`:

[image: cons vs. list]

That is, `(cons a b)` creates a cell whose `car` is `a` and `cdr` is `b`.
`(list a b)` creates a cell whose `car` is `a`, but the `cdr` is a *list*, and the `car` of *that* list is `b`, while its `cdr` is `nil`.

If `b` is a list, the one on the left will be a list which has `b` as its tail, and with `a` added at the front of `b`.
The one on the right will also be a list, but one which has `b` as its second *element*, not as its tail like you want.

To fix your program, you only need to replace your `list` with a `cons`.

*But* your function is not tail-recursive, because it does things with the result of the recursive call.

To make it tail-recursive, a good way is usually to make a helper function which has an accumulator parameter.

I would probably write it something like this:

```
(define (zip-cars l1 l2)
    (cons (car l1) (car l2)))

(define (zip-help l1 l2 result)
    (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
        result
        (zip-help (cdr l1) (cdr l2) (cons (zip-cars l1 l2) result))))

(define (zip l1 l2)
    (zip-help l1 l2 '()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `list` with `cons`. Then your code will evaluate to `(cons (cons (cons .... (cons ... '())) and your list will be properly terminated.

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))       
      '()                                  
      (cons (cons (car lst1) (car lst2))
            (zip (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))
```

then

```
(zip '(1 2 3 4) '(4 5 6))
=> '((1 . 4) (2 . 5) (3 . 6))
```

This is not tail-recursive, though, since after returning from `zip` the consing still has to be done.

**EDIT**

An example of a tail-recursive version:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (let loop ((lst1 lst1) (lst2 lst2) (res '()))
    (if (or (null? lst1) (null? lst2))       
        (reverse res)
        (loop (cdr lst1) 
              (cdr lst2) 
              (cons (cons (car lst1) (car lst2)) res)))))
```

Comment: I've got this : r5rs:body: no expression in body in: (r5rs:body)

Comment: Default parameters do not exist in R5RS it seems, I deleted that part. The other 2 work well for me in R5RS mode.

Comment: I don't completely get it how this is tail recursion (yes, I only understand the concept of tail recursion, when it comes to code, I really get confused..) can you explain a little bit, how this is tail recursion?..